# Dynamic change of selected value inside select tag in html page

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I'm a complete beginner in web development and I'm here to straight ask someone to create a javascript code to help my python flask app be a bit more user-friendly.

My HTML page consists of a table with several rows (it can be up to hundreds). and I want to allow the user to give rank to the most beautiful places on the table. My wish is to have the select tags change dynamically when new places get ranked or if the rank change.
For example, in the code below you can see that there are 5 places and 3 of them have already a selected rank.

My wish is that if a new place gets the rank 2, the already ranked places moved to a number up. The new place gets ranked 2 -> Place previously ranked 2 moved to 3 -> place ranked 3 moved to 4 and so on. In a way, I don’t have different places with the same rank.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
    <h1> Beatiful Places Ranking Page</h1>
    <h6> Please rank the following places you would like to travel </h6>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Region</th>
            <th>Ranking</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Torres del Paine National Park, Chile</td>
            <td>
                <select id="regions" name=0 >
                    <option value="0">-</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option selected value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                    <option value="7">7</option>
                    <option value="8">8</option>
                    <option value="9">9</option>
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Bagan, Myanmar</td>
            <td>
                <select id="regions" name=1 >
                    <option value="0">-</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option selected value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                    <option value="7">7</option>
                    <option value="8">8</option>
                    <option value="9">9</option>
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Monteverde Cloud Forest Biological Reserve, Costa Rica</td>
            <td>
                <select id="regions" name=2 >
                    <option value="0">-</option>
                    <option selected value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                    <option value="7">7</option>
                    <option value="8">8</option>
                    <option value="9">9</option>
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Anse Source d'Argent, Seychelles</td>
            <td>
                <select id="regions" name=3 >
                    <option value="0">-</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                    <option value="7">7</option>
                    <option value="8">8</option>
                    <option value="9">9</option>
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Grand Canyon, Arizona</td>
            <td>
                <select id="regions" name=4 >
                    <option value="0">-</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                    <option value="7">7</option>
                    <option value="8">8</option>
                    <option value="9">9</option>
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table> 
</body>
```

Thank you all in advance

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my own issue. So in case anyone is interested, here goes:
I've created a javascript code to update my ranks, please see it below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script type="text/javascript">

    // function to return true is a list has duplicated values
    function hasDuplicate(lista){
        let arr = listNoZero(lista); 
        return new Set(arr).size !== arr.length;
    }

    // function to return a list without zeros
    function listNoZero(lista){

        let n = [];
        for (i=0; i<lista.length; i++){ 
            value = parseInt(lista[i]); 
            if( value != 0 ){
                n.push(value);
            }
        }

        return n;

    }

    // function to return a list with names of the element and a list with values of element
    function getNameValue(documentElement){

        let n = [] ;// store name of documentElement
        let r = [] ;// store the value of documentElement 

        for (i=0; i<documentElement.length; i++){
            name = documentElement[i].name;
            value = documentElement[i].value;
            n.push(name);
            r.push(value)

        }

        return {
            'names': n,
            'ranks': r
        };
    }


    function changeDropdown(select){ 
        var name = select.name;
        var newGivenRank = parseInt(select.value);
 
        // get all elements with tag select
        const inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
        // call function getNameValue
        let input_info = getNameValue(inputs);
        let all_names = input_info.names,
            all_ranks = input_info.ranks;       


        // console.log(name + " " + newGivenRank);
        // console.log(all_names);
        // console.log(all_ranks); 
        // console.log(hasDuplicate(all_ranks))

        // change value while list still has duplicates
        // to initiate the loop 
        let dupli = hasDuplicate(all_ranks); 
        let number_rank = newGivenRank ;
        let ind = all_names.indexOf(name);

        let counter = 0
        while (dupli){
            counter++
            for (i=0; i<all_ranks.length; i++){
                let value = parseInt(all_ranks[i]);
                
                if (i == ind || value == 0){
                    continue;
                }

                if (value == number_rank){
                    let new_value = value + 1;
                    all_ranks[i] = new_value;
                    number_rank = new_value;
                    ind = i;

                }

            }  
            dupli = hasDuplicate(all_ranks);
            if(counter >= 500){
                alert('A problem has ocoured, please contact the tool administrator via contact button')
                break;
            }
        }

        console.log('updating ranks')

        // change the ranks on the select tag
        for (i=0; i<inputs.length; i++){
            let new_rank = all_ranks[i]
            inputs[i].value = new_rank
        }
    }


</script>

<body>
    <h1> Beatiful Places Ranking Page</h1>
    <h6> Please rank the following places you would like to travel </h6>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Region</th>
            <th>Ranking</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Torres del Paine National Park, Chile</td>
            <td>
                <select id="regions" name=112 onchange='changeDropdown(this)'>
                    <option value="0">-</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option selected value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                    <option value="7">7</option>
                    <option value="8">8</option>
                    <option value="9">9</option>
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Bagan, Myanmar</td>
            <td>
                <select id="regions" name=57 onchange='changeDropdown(this)'>
                    <option value="0">-</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option selected value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                    <option value="7">7</option>
                    <option value="8">8</option>
                    <option value="9">9</option>
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Monteverde Cloud Forest Biological Reserve, Costa Rica</td>
            <td>
                <select id="regions" name=67 onchange='changeDropdown(this)'>
                    <option value="0">-</option>
                    <option selected value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                    <option value="7">7</option>
                    <option value="8">8</option>
                    <option value="9">9</option>
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Anse Source d'Argent, Seychelles</td>
            <td>
                <select id="regions" name=3 onchange='changeDropdown(this)'>
                    <option value="0">-</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                    <option value="7">7</option>
                    <option value="8">8</option>
                    <option value="9">9</option>
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Grand Canyon, Arizona</td>
            <td>
                <select id="regions" name=25 onchange='changeDropdown(this)'>
                    <option value="0">-</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                    <option value="7">7</option>
                    <option value="8">8</option>
                    <option value="9">9</option>
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table> 
</body>
```